# Flutter project is working in debug version but not in the release version

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am working on a project and am trying to release the app but it is not working in the released version.

The app is perfectly fine in the debug version:
[image: this is the debug version]

but this app is not working in the released version:
[image: this is the released version]

Comment: When you are running the app on the debug version, you will be able to see the errors on the console. Read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

One of the common issues is that you may use expanded widget wrongly.
if you use expanded widget wrongly, it works on debug mode but when you want to release the application, it shows grey screen.

Please provide your debug console log when this screen appears in debug mode